# function outside the file cannot be called

Tags: android, kotlin, progress-bar

I have 2 class file, the first file declared the function, and then the MainActivity file called that function. And that shows me an error that the visible() and invisible() function are the unsolved references.

> EDIT: It showing the red color in the visible() and the invisible() function

I have this **Utils.kt** file

```
class Utils{

fun View.visible() {
    visibility = View.VISIBLE
}

fun View.invisible() {
    visibility = View.INVISIBLE
} }
```

and **MainActivity.kt** file

```
override fun showLoading() {
    progressBar.visible()
}

override fun hideLoading() {
    progressBar.invisible()
}
```

Comment: Does it show red color in View.visible() and invisible () lines?

Comment: I've edited my post thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**From the official Kotlin website:**

> Most of the time we define extensions on the top level, i.e. directly
>   under packages:

```
package foo.bar

fun Baz.goo() { ... }
```

> To use such an extension outside its declaring package, we need to
>   import it at the call site:

```
package com.example.usage

import foo.bar.goo // importing all extensions by name "goo"
                   // or
import foo.bar.*   // importing everything from "foo.bar"

fun usage(baz: Baz) {
    baz.goo()
}
```

In your case, just put all extension functions in the `Utils.kt` file and remove `class Utils`:

**Utils.kt**

```
import android.view.View

fun View.visible() {
    visibility = View.VISIBLE
}

fun View.invisible() {
    visibility = View.INVISIBLE
}
```